# Is it possible to force .Net Core on Linux to use CRLF?

Tags: .net-core

We have a .Net Core project that was developed using Windows. Now we started using Linux. But we run into some problems with some tests. We assert the *Message* inside *ArgumentNullException*. On Windows the final message will have **CRLF** but on Linux it will have **LF** (this new lines are put by the framework itself).

The issue is not just about the tests. We would like to somehow guarantee that no matter where we run our backend (we plan to start running on Linux), all those strings and files generated by the framework, are always using the Windows new line characters.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Set the NewLine property on TextWriter, e.g:

```
using (var stream = new StreamWriter(filename) { NewLine = "\r\n" })
    stream.WriteLine(...);
```

Comment: That seems like it would only support the one use case: using a `StreamWriter` not others like `Console.WriteLine`, which use `Environment.NewLine.

Comment: Haven't tested but I assume `Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n"` would work if you needed it.